# How to change Dataframe columns names

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have an array of values corresponding to stock symbols: `all = {AAPL, TSLA, MSFT}`.

I created a function to scrap their historical prices on YFinance.

```
            def Scrapping(symbol):
                aapl = yf.Ticker(symbol)
                ainfo = aapl.history(period='1y')
                global castex_date
                castex_date = ainfo.index

                return ainfo.Close

            all_Assets = list(map(Scrapping, all))  
            print(all_Assets)
```

This is an output sample:

```
[Date
2018-12-12 00:00:00-05:00    53.183998
2018-12-13 00:00:00-05:00    53.095001

Name: Close, Length: 1007, dtype: float64, Date
2018-12-12 00:00:00-05:00     24.440001
2018-12-13 00:00:00-05:00     25.119333

2022-12-08 00:00:00-05:00    247.399994
2022-12-09 00:00:00-05:00    245.419998
Name: Close, Length: 1007, dtype: float64]
```

The issue is that all these symbols' historical data have the same name 'Output'. When putting all of these in a dataframe, we get:

```
            df = pd.DataFrame(all_Assets)
            df2 = df.transpose()
            print(df2)

                               Close       Close       Close
Date                                                        
2018-12-12 00:00:00-05:00  53.183998   24.440001  104.500511
2018-12-13 00:00:00-05:00  53.095001   25.119333  104.854965
2018-12-14 00:00:00-05:00  52.105000   24.380667  101.578560
2018-12-17 00:00:00-05:00  50.826500   23.228001   98.570389
2018-12-18 00:00:00-05:00  51.435501   22.468666   99.605042
```

This creates an issue when plotting the DF.
I need these columns names to be equal to the `'symbol'` parameter of the function. SO, automatically, the column names would be AAPL TSLA MSFT

Comment: `df2.columns = all`. By the way `all` is a keyword, don't use it as your variable.

Comment: what should i replace all with ?

Comment: use something more descriptive, e.g `all_symbols = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'MSFT']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

all_symbols = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'MSFT']

def scrapping(symbol):
    ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    data = ticker.history(period='1y')
    return data['Close'].rename(symbol)

all_assets = map(scrapping, all_symbols)
df = pd.concat(all_assets, axis=1)
```

One-liner version:

```
df = pd.concat({symbol: yf.Ticker(symbol).history(period='1y')['Close']
                    for symbol in all_symbols}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                  AAPL        TSLA        MSFT
Date                                          
2022-02-14  167.863144  291.920013  292.261475
2022-02-15  171.749573  307.476654  297.680695
2022-02-16  171.511032  307.796661  297.333221
2022-02-17  167.863144  292.116669  288.626678
2022-02-18  166.292648  285.660004  285.846893
...                ...         ...         ...
2023-02-08  151.688400  201.289993  266.730011
2023-02-09  150.639999  207.320007  263.619995
2023-02-10  151.009995  196.889999  263.100006
2023-02-13  153.850006  194.639999  271.320007
2023-02-14  152.949997  203.729996  272.790009

[252 rows x 3 columns]
```